# What does 'Tuesday' quote mean?

Tags: meaning, quotes

On episode 11 from season 2 of the Fringe series, Peter says the following:

> If you tell me the US government is covering something up, I'll tell you it must be Tuesday.

What does that mean?

The scene was about doubting about how much the navy was sincere about some info.

Comment: I'd say it's simply a stock claim ("covering up") and a stock reply ("Tuesday").  Like many people would reply "forty-two".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The speaker is implying that the government covers things up very frequently, eg once a week.

It's a joke, basically, which compares the frequency of government cover ups to a real scheduled event like the office windows being cleaned, or a particular tv show being broadcast.